# Android: unable to change color of part of the text in textview

Tags: android, html, textview, spannable

Hi iam trying to change part of the text in textview to some color but iam unble to achieve it
i tried **fromHtml** , **spannable** and different methoda but its still not working.

My tries are as below:

**try1**

```
    Spannable wordtoSpan = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable("text 6 Months(180 days) or 8,000 kilometers.");

    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 15, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    tv.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

**try2**

```
    String str = "@Second @Service:6 Months(180 days) or 8,000 kilometers.";

    String[] str_array = str .split(" ");

    boolean isExists = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                 if (str_array[j].equals(str_array[i])) {
                     isExists = true;
                 }
             }
             if (str_array[i].startsWith("@") && !isExists) {
                 str  = str .replace(str_array[i],
                         "<font color='#8A0A0A'>" + str_array[i]
                                 + "</font>");
             } else if (str_array[i].contains("#")) {
                 str  = str .replaceAll(str_array[i],
                         "<font color='#000000'><b>" + str_array[i]
                                 + "</b></font>");
             }
         }

         tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
    }
```

**try3**

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text + "<font color=white>" + CepVizyon.getPhoneCode() + "</font><br><br>"
            + getText(R.string.currentversion) + CepVizyon.getLicenseText()));
```

**try4**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //method1
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.service);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + "give your string here long long longlong" + "</font>" + "<font color=\"#47a842\"></font>"));


        //method 2
        //SpannableStringBuilder WordtoSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder("give your string here long long longlong");
        //WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW),0,5,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //tv.setText(WordtoSpan);

    }
```

Any help is really appreciated.Thank you

Comment: @InnocentKiller hey i think i found the culprit..finally i found that in my layout file for TextView android:textAllCaps is causing the problem..with it, its not working but after removing that attribute its working perfectly

Comment: Okay great then, Happy coding...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this. The below code is perfectly working for me, i have tested it.

```
TextView ttt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
ttt.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

and here is output.

[image]

Comment: I think you have mistaken something. It's perfectly working fine for me. Even i have just tested now also.

Comment: its a simple textview but still not working update my code in try4 pls look at it

Comment: unfortunately tht too is not working for me....this is sick..u are able to but i cant

Comment: Have you imported this `import android.text.Html;`

Comment: yeahh i see your text is changing what wrong iam doing here...can u send me a test project if you dont mind

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48477/discussion-between-innocentkiller-and-teekib)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is running in my app perfectly.. May be it help you too

```
SpannableStringBuilder WordtoSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder(give your string here);
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW),starting Index, and the index of text from which you want to highlight you text,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
TextView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```